# R inference from one matrix to a data frame

Tags: r, matrix

I think this may be a very simple and easy question, but since I'm new to R, I hope someone can give me some outlines of how to solve it step by step. Thanks!

So the question is if I  have a (n * 2) matrix (say m) where the first column representing the index of the data in another data frame (say d)  and the second column representing some value(p value).

What i want to do is if the p value of some row r in m is less than 0.05,I will plot the data in d by the index indicated in the first column in row r of matrix m.

..............
The data is somewhat like what I draw below:

```
m:
ind p_value
2  0.02
23 0.03
56 0.12
64 0.54
105 0.04

d:
gene_id  s1  s2  s3  s4  ...  sn
IDH1    0.23 3.01 0 0.54 ...  4.02
IDH2    0.67 0 8.02 10.54 ...  0.72
...
```

so IDH2 is corresponding to the first line in m whose index column is 2

Comment: So IDH1 is index 1 but not 19

Comment: It's better to add clarifications in your question rather than as comments

Comment: I assume the x axis of the plot is 1, 2, ..., n along with the variable names in d? Also, do you want all lines on the same plot?

Comment: Thans for the note.

Comment: Instead of providing a line or two, provide a working example with desired output. In the meantime, the basic idea is `toplot <- d[ m[ m[,'p_value'] < .05,'ind'], ]`

Comment: I want to plot the hist diagram for each line in d if their p value is small, I don't want to plot them in the same plot. I just want to plot those whose P value(not calculated directly from raw data) is less than 0.05 in a hist diagram.

Comment: Thanks!! toplot <- d[ m[ m[,'p_value'] < .05,'ind'], ] works!!

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Thanks for the note, but I can't accept my own answer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toplot <- d[ m[ m[,'p_value'] < .05,'ind'], ]` works!